# Cannot connect to database through Intellij's Data Sources and Drivers

Tags: java, postgresql, intellij-idea, jdbc

I have a problem with displaying my databse structure through Intellij's Data Sources and Drivers page. I can connect to my database which is hosted on a redhat server through using application.properties of my spring project:

> spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://192.168.0.38:5432/cms_database

which works fine. Although, whenever I try to use Intellij's Data Sources and Drivers page I get an [Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iT72h.png):

> [3D000] FATAL: database "cms_database" does not exist.

I can test to connect to database "postgres" which returns a [Connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tA2JO.png):

> DBMS: PostgreSQL (ver. 13.0) Case sensitivity: plain=lower,
> delimited=exact Driver: PostgreSQL JDBC Driver (ver. 42.2.5, JDBC4.2)
> Ping: 16 ms SSL: no

Any help would be appreciated. If you need any extra info I would be happy to post!

Comment: do you have proper permission setup in pg_hba.conf file? looks like insufficient access rights.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to connect with settings from this example

[image]

I think you will set hostname wrongly

Comment: The OP is trying to connect to a PostgreSQL database, how would entering a configuration for an Oracle database work?

Comment: Sorry for taking ages to reply. Yes, it was the problem of using "localhost" instead of 192.168.0.38 Thank you for your help guys!

Comment: The image is missing :(