# DBMS: MySQL (no ver.) Case sensitivity: plain=mixed, delimited=exact Connection refused

Tags: mysql, intellij-idea, apple-m1, apple-silicon

Unable to connect to db using IntelliJ on mac m1.

Installed MySQL using Homebrew, I am able to access MySQL via terminal, I don't know what I am doing wrong.

I have tried reinstalling, changing the password, restarted my machine. but no hope

DBMS: MySQL (no ver.) Case sensitivity: plain=mixed, delimited=exact Connection refused

Comment: What params are you using when trying to connect using IntelliJ vs terminal? Please add details to your question, not in a comment. You could start by running `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'bind_address';` when connected via terminal.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65646647/cannot-connect-to-database-through-intellijs-data-sources-and-drivers

Comment: I had tempered with my.cnf file and had a different bind_address

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are encountering issues with your MySQL database while using Docker, the problem may be caused by the MYSQL_USER=root entry in your docker-compose.yaml file. This entry defines the user for your database environment and can create conflicts for the root user.

```
    db:
        image: mysql:8.0
        ports:
          - "3306:3306"
        environment:
          - MYSQL_ROOT_HOSTS=%
          - MYSQL_DATABASE=spring_boot_mysql
          - MYSQL_USER=root
          - MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=1
        volumes:
          - ./docker/volume_mysql:/var/lib/mysql
```

To resolve this issue, you should remove the MYSQL_USER=root entry and instead use one of the following to manage the root user password:

MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD
MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD

During my search for a solution, I found that the **Docker log** provided a helpful error message:

*[ERROR] [Entrypoint]: MYSQL_USER="root", MYSQL_USER and MYSQL_PASSWORD are for configuring a regular user and cannot be used for the root user.*

By removing MYSQL_USER=root from the docker-compose.yaml file, the problem was resolved, and the database connection was established successfully.

Here is the final database definition:

```
    db:
        image: mysql:8.0
        ports:
          - "3306:3306"
        environment:
          - MYSQL_ROOT_HOSTS=%
          - MYSQL_DATABASE=spring_boot_mysql
          - MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=1
        volumes:
          - ./docker/volume_mysql:/var/lib/mysql
```

I hope this information helps you resolve your issue.

Comment: Hi, @Rezende Diego, I'm already using MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD as you mentioned but having same issue. Do you know any other option to solve the issue? Thanks!

Comment: @Clawdidr : If you didn't map the port 3306 to33060  for example it cannot work.

From the mysql console displaying that the mapping occured:
`2024-03-18 05:16:02 2024-03-18T04:16:02.334729Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Bind-address: '::' port: 33060, socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock`

I can then open a connection to mysql using the port 33060.